# Which connectionstring to use in EF Code-first with an existing database

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, connection-string

The existing database was created in the project itself and resides on App_Data as prompted by visual studio while adding a new sql database item to the project.

So, should i use this string :

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;User Instance=true"
```

Or this one

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Database22;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Comment: @Mat I tried using the first one in another project. But when there was a change in model, it said you can't login or something of that sort. So, I am trying to be more careful. I don't want to create the database again if the model i am mapping isn't correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not following why you should use those connection strings with EF. Take a look at this:
 [How to: Build an EntityConnection Connection String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533.aspx)